# Git bash доступ по ssh

Tags: git, github

Кто ни будь может подсказать как это происходит?
Есть сайт на хостинге который дает доступ для одного по ssh.
Доступ удается получить но вот команда:

`git clone ssh:///home/username/host/dir.git`

выводит такую ошибку(fatal: unable to create thread: Resource temporarily unavailable). Может нарушаю какую-то последовательность?

Как тогда работать с хостингом локально? То есть клонировать себе на машину поработать потом сделать `git push`

Файл id_rsa.pub нужен если получаете доступ по паролю? Так как на своей машине есть id_rsa.pub от github. На Github всё работает чудесно.
И как быть если приходится с несколькими разными хостерами работать?

Comment: Спасибо, я уже это читал но это не помогает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Доступ удается получить

и этот доступ вы получаете, насколько я понял, подключаясь к серверу командой вида:

```
$ ssh username@server
```

а хранилище располагается на этом сервере в каталоге `/home/username/host/dir.git`

---

тогда клонировать хранилище с сервера вам надо такой командой (выполнять её надо локально):

```
$ git clone username@server:/home/username/host/dir.git
```

Comment: собственно, я даже не думал, что можно истолковать ответ как руководство к выполнению команд **на сервере**. конечно, это надо выполнять локально. окей, сейчас уточню формулировки.

Comment: извиняюсь, но твой ответ сработал когда на прямую без подключения к серверу ввел. Оказывает решение было рядом. Спасибо помог

Comment: так этой командой (`git clone ...`) вы («под капотом») именно **подключаетесь** к серверу. и именно по протоколу *ssh*. понимаю, что для пользователя *ms/windows*, сбитого с толку [дырявыми абстракциями](http://russian.joelonsoftware.com/Articles/LeakyAbstractions.html), это может быть совсем не очевидным. что ж, добро пожаловать в *реальный* мир!

Comment: вы клонировали хранилище. дальше действуете как в миллионе руководств описано: вносите изменения, делаете add, commit, push. требуются ли в **вашем случае** ещё какие-то дополнительные действия — уточняйте у администратора/руководителя/и т.д. и т.п.